# Double Machine Learning (DML) and variables 'standardization

Tags: stata, lasso, standardization

I am trying to use the command that STATA has for DML (Cross-fit partialing-out lasso linear regression; xporegress) but I have some questions for which I could not find a solution:

1. I know that usually with Lasso methods we have to standardize the variables. I am wondering, is the command doing this automatically ? Moreover, as DML is not about predictions but inference, should the variables of interest also be standardized? Or should there be any standardization at all in Double Machine Learning?
2. About this standardization procedure, I know there is a whole debate about whether categorical variables should be standardized. I have a few as well as controls and I am currently just transforming them to be considered as dummy variables. (i. command). Do you think that's enough ?
3. Lastly, I am also considering applying a log-scale to some of my continuous variables (e.g average income and expenditures). Do you think this is feasible after standardizing the variables?
4. Is there a way to create automatically interactions between variables as controls ?

To put it all in context, I am trying to estimate the effect of two variables (one categorical/dummy and one a continuous one) while taking into account the effect of a bunch of controls.

If you have any ideas about these questions or any general comments, please let me know.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1613326-double-machine-learning-dml-in-stata-xporegress-command